# how to trim backslash?

Tags: perl

I need to remove backslash from an array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use Test::WWW::Selenium;
use Test::More "no_plan";
use Test::Exception; 

@array = "qwerty-uioplkjadsfcxhbdhjjkgkmnvkgmkgmkgkglmzbcd\-\dfgtg\qwerty";
```

i need to remove `\` in the above array. i tried with `@array =~ s/\\//;`but i'm unable to do it.

After removing backslash from an array, an array should contain like below:

```
    print @array;

    output:

qwerty-uioplkjadsfcxhbdhjjkgkmnvkgmkgmkgkglmzbcd - dfgtg qwerty
```

how can i just remove the backslash ?

Comment: `@array =~ s/\\//;` doesn't compile.  You'll have to fix your assertions (and explain where the data is coming from) before the question will actually make sense.

Comment: @DavidO: dat is the command execution retrieving from an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: double quotes will interpolate, so you should write `'...d\-\dfgtg\qwerty";'` instead of   `"..";` or use [`q{ }`.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

Then there is `@array =~ s/\\//;` which isn't valid syntax. I guess you wanted to write `s#\\##g for @array;`.

This code works:

```
my @array = q{qwerty-uioplkjadsfcxhbdhjjkgkmnvkgmkgmkgkglmzbcd\-\dfgtg\qwerty};
say "--> '$_'" for @array;

s#\\##g for @array;
say "--> '$_'" for @array;
```

The output:

```
--> 'qwerty-uioplkjadsfcxhbdhjjkgkmnvkgmkgmkgkglmzbcd\-\dfgtg\qwerty'
--> 'qwerty-uioplkjadsfcxhbdhjjkgkmnvkgmkgmkgkglmzbcd-dfgtgqwerty'
```

BTW: If you have only one element in your array, you should probably use a [scalar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types).

Comment: @ Sebastin : I want to remove those slashes and removed slash place should be left with space. Is it possible something like to replace the \ with space ? or any better way ?

Comment: Simply use `s#\\# #g` instead of `s#\\##g` then.

Comment: Applying substitution (s///) to @array will act on scalar(@array) at test.pl
Can't modify array dereference in substitution (s///) at test.pl, ne
ar "s#\\# #g;"
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Use the substitution like I did in the answer: `s#\\# #g for @array;`

Comment: @ Sebastin : Thank you. It's working fine. But what makes difference ?

Comment: When you try to apply the substitution on the array (eg `@array =~ s/...`) you are actually applying it on the scalar value of @array, because `s///` works on scalar values. The scalar value of @array is `1` (the arrays length). Thats why you get the warning. `s/// for @array` applies the substitution to each element of @array and therefore works.

Comment: Thank you very much,Sebastin. It's very helpful.